# For loop with iteration in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-blade

I would like to know what to do in Blade to have the equivalent of this code. I need to do an iteration inside a foreach. I see the blade loop variable like `$loop->index` or `$loop->remaining` but I need to know how to use it to make the equivalent of the code below.

```php
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $result[$i]['id'];
    $result[$i]['name'];
    $result[$i]['email']; 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank mhrabiee. i found the solution.

```
@foreach($things as $thing)

 @if( $loop->first or $loop->iteration  <= 3 )

       <tr>
          <td>{{$thing)->id}}</td>
          <td>{{$thing)->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$thing)->email}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
 @endforeach
```

this start first iteration

```
$loop->first
```

and this stop iteration after 3 loop

```
$loop->iteration  <= 3
```

and voila !

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit vague but exact **equivalent** of your code is something like this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
 {{ $result[$i]['id'] }}
 {{ $result[$i]['name'] }}
 {{ $result[$i]['email'] }}
@endfor
```

By the way if you want to iterate through something like `$results` array you can do this:

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
    <div>{{ $result->id }}</div>
    <div>{{ $result->name }}</div>
    <div>{{ $result->email }}</div>
@endforeach
```

PS: You can learn more about for loops in Laravel's Blade [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops).